# Web scraping and promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, web-scraping, promise

I am using cheerio and node to do web scraping, but I have a problem with promises. I can scrape an article list from a page but in that list, we have more links for single pages. I need to scrape single pages as well for each item on the list.
I will show you my code for the better solution.

```
import rp from 'request-promise'
import cheerio from 'cheerio'
import conn from './connection'

const flexJob = `https://www.flexjobs.com`
const flexJobCategory = ['account-management', 'bilingual']

class WebScraping {

    //list of article e.g for page 2
    results = [] // [[title], [link for page],...]
    contentPage = [] //content for each page

    scrapeWeb(link) {
        let fullLink = `${link}/jobs/${flexJobCategory[1]}?page=2`
        const options = {
            uri: fullLink,
            transform(body) {
                return cheerio.load(body)
            }
        }
        rp(options)
            .then(($) => {
                console.log(fullLink)
                $('.featured-job').each((index, value) => {

                    //html nodes
                    let shortDescription = value.children[1].children[1].children[3].children[1].children[1].children[0].data
                    let link = value.children[1].children[1].children[1].children[1].children[1].children[0].attribs.href
                    let pageLink = flexJob + '' + link
                    let title = value.children[1].children[1].children[1].children[1].children[1].children[0].children[0].data
                    let place = value.children[1].children[1].children[1].children[1].children[3].children[1].data
                    let jobType = value.children[1].children[1].children[1].children[1].children[3].children[0].children[0].data
                    this.results.push([title, '', pageLink.replace(/\s/g, ''), '', shortDescription.replace(/\n/g, ''), place, jobType, 'PageContent::: '])
                })
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.results.forEach(element => {
                    console.log('link: ', element[2])
                    this.scrapePage(element[2])
                });
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('print content page', this.contentPage)
            })
            .then(() => {
                //this.insertIntoDB()
                console.log('insert into db')
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })

    }

    /**
     * It's going to scrape all pages from list of jobs
     * @param {Any} pageLink 
     * @param {Number} count 
     */
    scrapePage(pageLink) {
        let $this = this
        //console.log('We are in ScrapePage' + pageLink + ': number' + count)
        //this.results[count].push('Hello' + count)
        let content = ''
        const options = {
            uri: pageLink,
            transform(body) {
                return cheerio.load(body)
            }
        }
        rp(options)
            .then(($) => {
                //this.contentPage.push('Hello' + ' : ');
                console.log('Heloo')
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
    /**
     * This method is going to insert data into Database
    */
    insertIntoDB() {
        conn.connect((err) => {
            var sql = "INSERT INTO contact (title, department, link, salary, short_description, location, job_type, page_detail) VALUES ?"
            var values = this.results
            conn.query(sql, [values], function (err) {
                if (err) throw err
                conn.end()
            })
        })
    }
}
let webScraping = new WebScraping()
let scrapeList =  webScraping.scrapeWeb(flexJob)
```

So, at 'scrapeWeb' method, at second '.then', I am calling 'scrapePage' method, however, the third promise executed before promise inside 'scrapePage' method.

Answer (score 2):

You need a little more control flow at that stage. You do not want that `.then()`'s promise to resolve until all the calls are resolved.

You could use a Promise library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) to do a `Promise.each` or a `Promise.map` for all the results you want to run.

Or use async/await to set up like `.then(async () => {})` and *do not use .forEach*.

```
for(let element of this.results){
  console.log('link: ', element[2])
  await this.scrapePage(element[2])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a race condition problem.

The first tweak you'll need is having `scrapePage` returning a `Promise`.

```
scrapePage(pageLink) {
        let $this = this
        let content = ''
        const options = {
            uri: pageLink,
            transform(body) {
                return cheerio.load(body)
            }
        }
        return rp(options);
    }
```

In the second than, you need to invoke all child pages scraping eg :

```
.then(() => {
return Promise.all(this.results.map(childPage => this.scrapePage(childPage)));
})
```

This will wrap all scrapes of child pages into promises and only if all of them are resolved the code will flow.